# encoding issue on form.serialize(); Some specials character displaying as ASCII code

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I am having a problem with special character in javascript.
I have a form with a input text that has the following string:

```
10/10/2010
```

after a form.serialize(); I get this string as

```
10%2F10%2F2010
```

The '/' character is converted to its ASCII code %2F.

I would be able to convert that using `String.fromCharCode(ascii_code)` but I have many inputs in my form so these string is somenthing like:

```
var=14&var=10%2F10%2F2010&var=10%2F10%2F2010&var=10%2F10%2F2010
```

Just an example to state that I would have to go through this string ("manually") and find those value and convert it.

Is there any easy way to perform that conversion?
Strange thing because I did not have that problem before, I am not sure why this is happening now.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("10%2F10%2F2010")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happens that way because that's [how it's meant to be](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in **standard URL-encoded
>   notation**. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form
>   elements.

As far as I know, there's no native jQuery function to unserialize but your post suggests you already got that and are only stuck in the [URL-encoded strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

> `decodeURIComponent(encodedURI)`
> Decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component previously created by encodeURIComponent or
>   by a similar routine.